# What is "Automatic Source" in depcache.cc in the source code package of apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, source-packages

when browsing source code for apt package manager, I wanted to find out the inner logic of `pkgDepCache::Policy::GetCandidateVer` function.

```
pkgCache::VerIterator pkgDepCache::Policy::GetCandidateVer(PkgIterator const &Pkg)
{
   /* Not source/not automatic versions cannot be a candidate version 
      unless they are already installed */
   VerIterator Last(*(pkgCache *)this,0);

   for (VerIterator I = Pkg.VersionList(); I.end() == false; ++I)
   {
      if (Pkg.CurrentVer() == I)
     return I;

      for (VerFileIterator J = I.FileList(); J.end() == false; ++J)
      {
     if ((J.File()->Flags & Flag::NotSource) != 0)
        continue;

     /* Stash the highest version of a not-automatic source, we use it
        if there is nothing better */
     if ((J.File()->Flags & Flag::NotAutomatic) != 0 ||
         (J.File()->Flags & Flag::ButAutomaticUpgrades) != 0)

      ...
```

What are "**automatic version**" and "**automatic source**" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A source for apt, as given in apt's `sources.list` for example, can have a `Release` file which specifies various properties of the source. For example, the [`Release` file of Ubuntu back ports for 16.04](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/Release):

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: xenial-backports
Version: 16.04
Codename: xenial
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 14:06:49 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Xenial Backports
NotAutomatic: yes
ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes
MD5Sum:
 f1647057d0c93fc58961ea0d03f5e524           244120 Contents-powerpc
```

Note the last few fields in seen here. Those are the same ones being tested in that code. An automatic source is one in which `NotAutomatic` is **not** `yes`. These fields are used for assigning a default priority to sources by apt. From [`man apt_preferences`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html):

```
   If the target release has been specified then APT uses the following
   algorithm to set the priorities of the versions of a package. Assign:

   priority 1
       to the versions coming from archives which in their Release files
       are marked as "NotAutomatic: yes" but not as "ButAutomaticUpgrades:
       yes" like the Debian experimental archive.

   priority 100
       to the version that is already installed (if any) and to the
       versions coming from archives which in their Release files are
       marked as "NotAutomatic: yes" and "ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes" like
       the Debian backports archive since squeeze-backports.
```

You can read more about how these priorities are used by apt in the manpage.

Now, in the first comment, "not source" means a package version which is **not** from an apt source (an entry in `sources.list`, for example). This would be a version that's already installed, so the information comes from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` (you can check the output of `apt-cache policy` for an installed package to see this). "Not automatic versions" are from a source that's marked `NotAutomatic` as described above.
Such sources are called "not automatic" in the second comment.

Comment: so does get candidateVer method take current software dependencies into consideration when seeking candidate?